# How to change the order of the messages from JSON?

Tags: android, json, parsing, listview, message

I have such JSON response with messages from the server:

```html
response: {
count: 74246,
items: [{
  id: 343194,
  body: 'Message 3',
  user_id: 123,
  from_id: 123,
  date: 1436513626,
  read_state: 1,
  out: 0
}, {
  id: 343190,
  body: 'Message 2',
  user_id: 123,
  from_id: 321,
  date: 1436513502,
  read_state: 1,
  out: 1
}, {
  id: 343187,
  body: 'Message 1',
  user_id: 123,
  from_id: 123,
  date: 1436513198,
  read_state: 1,
  out: 0
}]
}
```

I put it into the listview and I have such order:

- Message 3
- Message 2
- Message 1

But I want to get the next order:

- Message 1
- Message 2
- Message 3

So it means that the newest messages should be from the bottom to top. Probably I should build the listview from the bottom? But how?
What should I do to achieve this? 
And sorry for my English :)

Comment: a) How are you creating your listview? b) Who is generating the JSON?

Comment: prolly you need to sort data ...

Comment: do you want to sort this based on date or message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Set reverse order** on **ArrayList**:

```
ArrayList<Your_Model> mList = new ArrayList<Your_Model>();
```

Set data in **mList** from **JSON**:

Whenever you want to get **List** on **reverse order**, put below code.

```
Collections.reverse(mList);
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your "items" array in JsonArray then you should get data like,

```
     for(int i=array.length()-1; i<=0; i--){
         // get your messages from "items" array.  
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **I'm assuming that you want to sort your list of messages based on `date` field in the response.**

Create an `ArrayList` of `MyClass` from this JSON response, say `mylist` and create a comparator class as below:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyClass> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyClass lhs, MyClass rhs) {
        if (ldate.getDate() > rdate.getDate()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (ldate.getDate() < rdate.getDate()) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

`MyClass` is a model class for above JSON response.

Use this `Comparator` class with you `ArrayList` as below:

```
Collections.sort(mylist,new MyComparator());
```

I hope this will help you.